# Complex number proof

Tags: complex-numbers

Let *f(x)*, *g(x)* $\in \mathbb C[x].$
Prove that if *f(x) | g(x)* and *g(x) | f(x)*, then there exists a nonzero
$c \in \mathbb C$ such that $f(x) = c * g(x)$
(You may use the fact that for any *p(x), q(x)* $\in \mathbb C [x],$
*deg(p(x)q(x)) = deg(p(x)) + deg(q(x)).)*

How would i begin the proof for this question?

Comment: Start by writing down what it means that $f$ divides $g$. And that $g$ divides $f$. Then use the degree formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Let $\ h=g/f.\,$ Then $\,h\,$ and $\,1/h\,$ are both polynomials so $\,\deg\,h = \,\ldots\,\Rightarrow\, h\in \Bbb C$

Comment: If you allow $\rm\,0\mid f\ (\!\iff\! f=0)\,$ then you need to also handle the degenerate cases when $\,f,g=0.\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the following fact useful. Think about why it's true.

> If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are (nonzero) polynomials with complex coefficients and $f(x)\mid g(x)$ then $\deg(f)\leq\deg(g)$.